# Default browser tooltip is not shown because of RxJS debounce

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, rxjs

Basically what I want to achieve is to listen to 'mousemove' event attached to document and once I hover on element I check if it has overflowed text, and if it does I truncate it and add title attribute to target element with full text so that when user hovers on it browser shows default tooltip with this text.

This logic works perfectly fine itself but it has major flaw. It kills performance of my app because I use getComputedStyle() inside of it.

In order to resolve this I tried to use RxJS debounce and it works great. But if user moves mouse quickly and then stops so that there is only 1 event for that element is emitted then tooltip is added to DOM but not shown.

As I understand what is happening from browser perspective everything works fine because when user hovered on element there was no title yet and once it was added user didn't move the mouse anymore so tooltip is not shown.

```
fromEvent(document, 'mouseenter')
.pipe(
  debounceTime(20),
  tap(($event: Event) => {
    this.addTooltip($event);
  })
)
.subscribe();
```

The question is does anyone know how can I workaround this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you can try to trigger the `mousemove` event on the code using `Element.dispatchEvent()` method. I've tried to do something as an example in this [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-a-60836041-6433166?file=src/app/app.component.ts) (yes, it's angular, but I'm not using andy angular feature beyond the separation of concerns markup-javascript-css => everything else is just pure javascript). Basically what I did was:

```html
<p title="house">
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
```

```js
// track the html elements that currently have a title modified
// this avoids additional unnecessary listeners on a single HTML element
private elementWithListenerAdded = new Set();

...

fromEvent(document, "mousemove")
  .pipe(
    debounceTime(20),
    tap(($event: MouseEvent) => {
      this.addTooltip($event);
    })
  )
  .subscribe();

...

addTooltip(evt: MouseEvent) {
  const $tag = evt.target;

  // I'm assuming that you don't want any tooltip on
  // header, HTML or body tags
  if (
    ($tag as any).tagName === "HEADER" ||
    ($tag as any).tagName === "HTML" ||
    ($tag as any).tagName === "BODY" ||
    this.elementWithListenerAdded.has($tag)
  ) {
    return;
  }

  const elementWithListenerAdded = this.elementWithListenerAdded;

  elementWithListenerAdded.add($tag);

  // remove the event listener when the mouse leave the element
  // and restore the original title
  const originalTitle = ($tag as any).getAttribute("title");
  function removeEventListener() {
    $tag.removeEventListener("mouseleave", this);
    elementWithListenerAdded.delete($tag);
    ($tag as any).setAttribute("title", originalTitle);
  }

  $tag.addEventListener("mouseleave", removeEventListener);

  ($tag as any).setAttribute("title", "just a test");

  ($tag as any).dispatchEvent(
    new MouseEvent("mousemove", {
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true,
      view: window
    })
  );
}
```